# Remove entire json object from JSON array

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to update the list of contacts by deleting whatever contact is requested to be deleted by user input.  In other words, trying to remove an entire JSON object from a JSON array in my PostgreSQL database from a Node.js script, but I get error

> error: null value in column "info" of relation "user_emails" violates
> not-null constraint

I double-checked and the value and everything is there. When I try it here [online](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3y3jte4tr) it works, but on my server it returns the error. How can I fix this?

```
    DROP table if exists user_emails;
CREATE table user_emails (
  id serial not null PRIMARY KEY,
  info jsonb NOT NULL
  );
  insert into user_emails(info) values('{
  "userid": "4",
  "mailbox": "johndoe@example.com",
  "contacts": [
    {
      "id": "ghr3gk8dez4",
      "email": "janedoe@gmail.com",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "first_name": "Jane",
      "date_created": "2022-05-08T20:52:47.967Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "th2lypvoxpr1652045110763",
      "email": "aldoe@gmail.com",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "first_name": "Al",
      "date_created": "2022-05-08T21:25:10.763Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "ld123tqicmj1652045372671",
      "email": "stdoe@gmail.com",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "first_name": "Stella",
      "date_created": "2022-05-08T21:29:32.671Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "1ltbrpbj8xf1652045768004",
      "email": "mdoe@mail.com",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "first_name": "Marta",
      "date_created": "2022-05-08T21:36:08.004Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "1dgntfwvsmf1652045832589",
      "email": "nala@mail.com",
      "last_name": "La",
      "first_name": "Na",
      "date_created": "2022-05-08T21:37:12.589Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "ll3z1n0jkhc1652045984538",
      "email": "bdoe@mail.com",
      "last_name": "doe",
      "first_name": "bruno",
      "date_created": "2022-05-08T21:39:44.538Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "kzr996xxxt1652046050118",
      "email": "pp@mail.com",
      "last_name": "Perf",
      "first_name": "Perf",
      "date_created": "2022-05-08T21:40:50.118Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "41bovnvsihq1652046121940",
      "email": "mmd@mm.com",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "first_name": "Melinda",
      "date_created": "2022-05-08T21:42:01.940Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "tnjlj4dcg2b1652046154937",
      "email": "keke@j.com",
      "last_name": "Kee",
      "first_name": "Kee",
      "date_created": "2022-05-08T21:42:34.937Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "hor0wafkuj1652046684582",
      "email": "jojo@mail.com",
      "last_name": "Jo",
      "first_name": "Jo",
      "date_created": "2022-05-08T21:51:24.582Z"
    }
  ],
  "auto_reply": false,
  "email_name": "johndoe",
  "signatures": [],
  "domain_name": "example.com",
  "date_created": "2022-05-08T20:39:54.881Z",
  "forward_email": [],
  "auto_reply_messages": []
}');
```

this is my UPDATE

```
UPDATE user_emails SET info = (SELECT jsonb_agg(j) 
                               FROM jsonb_array_elements(user_emails.info->'contacts') as t(j) 
                               WHERE j ->> 'id' not in ('ghr3gk8dez4'));
                               
SELECT * FROM user_emails;
```

Comment: Do you really want to set the column to an array, or do you want to set the `info->'contact'` object property to an array?

Comment: This would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: What do you mean by normalized? This is as normal as jsonb gets yes?

Comment: Using json is de-normalizing. With a properly normalized model it would be as easy as  `delete from contacts where id = 'ghr3gk8dez4'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : yes if I wanted to delete the entire row I could use the id of the row which is present there but that's not what I'm trying to do here. I'm just wanting to update the list of contacts of a user by deleting the contact the user wants to delete

Comment: The list of contacts shouldn't be stored in a JSON array. They should be stored in a table of their own with a foreign key back to `user_emails`. This is a text-book example of a one-to-many relationship. Postgres is a relational database, so use it as one. Not as a glorified, dumb data store for JSON values.

Comment: Something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=74518c3e58b1defff6cf8eb3288dce8c

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : it would be much easier like this I know but in terms of resources and performance to be honest it's not convenient at all because now I have to create all these different tables and managing foreign keys is a headache I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : if you run my query here : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=652eaf9808cdc2501455c5b32fa83cc8. It works just like it should. It removes the row very clean. So I'm just very confused with the error on my server.

Comment: "*now I have to create all these different tables and managing foreign keys is a headache*" - then a relational database is not the right tool for you

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: dude, that's why I'm using PG and JSONB, best of both yeah? :)

Comment: Your update can never work. Your `jsonb_agg()` only aggregates the elements from the `contacts` array and ignores all other keys from your JSON value. You are essentially _replacing_ the entire JSON with **only** the contacts array. The not null constraint violation probably stems from the fact that the id you are trying to remove doesn't exist, so jsonb_agg() comes up with an empty array.

Comment: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I understand. You're speaking to someone who is coming from MYSQL, MariaDB, PHP etc. That's my background. Started coding in Nodejs a few years back, discovered jsonb and I would NEVER go back. Nice try dude. Matter of fact, every single API out there uses JSON structure so there's no way I'm changing the structure of my entire software because you know DEADLINE and because BUDGET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonb_agg`, like so many other aggregate functions, returns `NULL` if there are no rows to aggregate. You might be looking to `COALESCE` it to an empty array instead:

```
UPDATE user_emails
SET info = jsonb_set(
  user_emails.info,
  '{contacts}',
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT jsonb_agg(j) 
      FROM jsonb_array_elements(user_emails.info->'contacts') as t(j) 
      WHERE j ->> 'id' not in ('ghr3gk8dez4')
    ),
    '[]'::jsonb
  )
);
```

Comment: This deletes everything! This is not the task. The task is to update the list of contacts by deleting whatever contacts the user is wanting the delete.

Comment: @Grogu Yes, you're updating the whole `info`, not just the contacts. I just solved the non-null violation. To update the object, use `jsonb_set(info, 'contacts', …)`

Comment: how would your last example work in real time?

Comment: @Grogu [Like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=148b16f022454e30559e4b2e01071e37)

Comment: But this deletes the entire list of contacts. How to just delete the one the user wants to delete?

Comment: @Grogu No it doesn't? User 4 still has 9 contacts (instead of the previous 10). It's only user 3 that has no contacts, which I inserted to demonstrate the issue (making"*online it works, but on my server it returns the error*" reproducable).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an efficient way to do that using only built-in functions.

There is an operator `#-` that removes an element by specifying the path, e.g. `info #- '{contacts, 0}'` would do what you want. However, it's not straight forward to build such a "path array" directly.

I would write a function that finds the index of the contact to be deleted and generates the path array:

```
create or replace function find_entry(p_info jsonb, p_id text)
  returns text[]
as
$$
  select array['contacts', (idx - 1)::text]
  from jsonb_array_elements(p_info -> 'contacts') with ordinality as t(element, idx)
  where t.element ->> 'id' = p_id
  limit 1;
$$
language sql;
```

The `-1` is necessary because SQL uses 1-based numbering, but in JSON arrays start at zero.

With that function you can then do:

```
update user_emails 
   set info #- find_entry(info, 'ghr3gk8dez4')
where ...
```